# Integral involving Cauchy Int Formula

Tags: complex-analysis, cauchy-integral-formula

I have to evaluate the following integral:

$$I=\oint_C\frac{s^3+2s}{(s-z)^3}\;ds$$

Case 1: $C$ is an arbitrary closed curve oriented counter-clockwise and $z$ is within $C$.

I'll rewrite as follows:

$$I=\oint_C\frac{f(s)}{(s-z)^3}\;ds$$

I immediately notice the following:

$$I=f''(z)=\frac{2!}{2\pi i}\oint_C\frac{s^3+2s}{s-z}\;ds$$

Using Cauchy Integral Formula:

$$I=\pi i\cdot 6z=6\pi i z$$

However, I'm also to consider a second case where $z$ lies without $C$. I know the answer is supposed to be $0$, but I can't find anything in my book on when this happens and why it happens. Any insight would be much appreciated.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/520131/when-a-pole-lies-outside-the-circle-of-integration-what-does-cauchy-integral-fo

Comment: Thank you for the link. Why mathematically does the integral evaluate to zero of the point lies outside the curve?

Comment: Well, following what has been written in that link, I assume that the function turns out to be analytic in $C$ if $z$ lies outside of it. So, it's $0$. http://www.math.columbia.edu/~rf/complex3.pdf

Comment: So I can simply say that because $f(s)$ is a polynomial, it must be analytic, finishing the proof?

Comment: That seems to be fine.

Comment: It's been a while since I've done complex analysis.