# $\int_{C}\frac{z}{(z-2)(z-1)}dz$ where $C:|z-2|=0.5$. Is my work correct?

Tags: complex-analysis

I dissolved it into partial fractions:

$\frac{2}{z-2}$ and $\frac{-1}{z-1}$. Then I dissolved the integral as the sum of these two integrals. The pole $z=1$ lies outside $C$. I didn't know what to do in that case. I went to this thread :[When a pole lies outside the circle of integration, what does Cauchy integral formula state?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/520131/when-a-pole-lies-outside-the-circle-of-integration-what-does-cauchy-integral-fo) . From what I read, the integral should be 0 because $\frac{1}{z-1}$ seems analytic in the given region.

I evaluated the second integral to be $4\pi i$ by Cauchy's integral formula.

Also, aside from this question, what am I supposed to do in the general case where the pole lies outside the circle?

Answer (score 2):

Your result is correct but you may have a second look at Cauchy's integral formula to see the following:

$$f(2) = \frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_C \frac{f(z)}{z-2}\;dz \mbox{ with } f(z) = \frac{z}{z-1} \Rightarrow \int_C \frac{f(z)}{z-2}\;dz = 2\pi i \frac{2}{2-1}=4\pi i$$